# How to solve "no cipher suites in common" during SSL Handshake?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I am building a B2B service by Tomcat 8 + Java 8.
But one of my customer can't connect to my services by using SSL.
After adding the SSL debug parameter: "-Djavax.net.debug=ssl", I see the error messages:

```
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
https-jsse-nio-8445-exec-9, READ: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 62
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1490342314 bytes = { 192, 161, 228, 31, 66, 175, 222, 13, 79, 128, 217, 81, 18, 152, 169, 58, 114, 35, 201, 201, 147, 74, 131, 2, 213, 145, 181, 76 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, Unknown 0xff:0x3, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-7, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
https-jsse-nio-8445-exec-9, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

How to solve error?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my experience sharing to solve the issue.

1. Enable SSL debug parameter "-Djavax.net.debug=ssl", and found the error is "no cipher suites in common"
2. After googling some pages, I installed "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction", http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html, it added some cryptography algorithmes at JVM level, ex: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, but it didn't solve the problem.
   PS. Ciphers.java is a useful code, which can show available cipher suites in JVM level.
3. I captured the network packets and analyzed in wireshark, it showed after client send ClientHello, my server disconnected the connection immediatedly.
4. Since my customer can't test with my, I have to reproduce the problem by my own to speed up the troubleshooting process. Then I found the code SslPoke.java and modified it. It can simulate client's request by using different combinations of TLS versions or cipher suites. And I can simulate same error log by my own, it helped a lot.
5. Then, again google, I found I can specify cipher suites in Tomcat's server.xml, ex:

`<Connector port="${https.port}" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" sslProtocol="TLS" ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256... " />`

I added the config, tested by SslPoke and passed, the case closed.

Hope the experience can help others who are facing the same problem.
Don't forget to check cipher suites configurations in JVM / Web Container / App Server...
And those following codes are also very useful, thanks for experts who provide them.

Best Regards,
Leon

Code: Ciphers.java, found from: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-779171661.html

```
public class Ciphers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

        String[] defaultCiphers = ssf.getDefaultCipherSuites();
        String[] availableCiphers = ssf.getSupportedCipherSuites();

        TreeMap ciphers = new TreeMap();

        for(int i=0; i<availableCiphers.length; ++i )
            ciphers.put(availableCiphers[i], Boolean.FALSE);

        for(int i=0; i<defaultCiphers.length; ++i )
            ciphers.put(defaultCiphers[i], Boolean.TRUE);

        System.out.println("Default\tCipher");
        for(Iterator i = ciphers.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry cipher=(Map.Entry)i.next();

            if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(cipher.getValue()))
                System.out.print('*');
            else
                System.out.print(' ');

            System.out.print('\t');
            System.out.println(cipher.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

Code: SslPoke.java, found from: https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029

```
public class SslPoke {

    private static javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory getFactorySimple() throws Exception {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");

        context.init(null, null, null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("https.cipherSuites", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA");

        try {
            String urlStr ="https://<your host>:<your port>";
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);

            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getFactorySimple();

            connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

            while (in.available() > 0) {
                System.out.print(in.read());
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully connected");

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```